# got error on xcode7... I can't use 'new()' on xcode7?

Tags: swift

The error said that 'new()' is unavailable for Swift::use object initializers instead. Don't know how to fix...

```
   func showImage(notif:NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notif.userInfo as NSDictionary! {

         //the code below is the one i got error for
        let photos:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.new()

        let photo:IDMPhoto = IDMPhoto(image: userInfo["img"] as! UIImage!)
        photos.addObject(photo)
        let browser:IDMPhotoBrowser = IDMPhotoBrowser(photos: photos as [AnyObject]!)
        browser.delegate = self
        browser.displayActionButton = false
        self.presentViewController(browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `NSMutableArray.new()` to `NSMutableArray()`.